# PDO MySQL prepared INSERT syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, syntax-error

Have seen tons of similar questions but still can't find out what's going on.

I'm using PHP's PDO to prepare a statement like that:

```
try{
    $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $date (name, surname, email, phone, comment) VALUES (:name, :surname, :email, :phone, :comment)");
    $statement->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $statement->bindParam(':surname', $surname);
    $statement->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $statement->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
    $statement->bindParam(':comment', $comment);

    $statement->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    die("Connection to database failed: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Have tried escaping everything with [] and specifying the database name before table name, but keep getting

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in 
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near '2017-08-11 (name, surname, email, 
phone, comment) VALUES ('Test', 'Test', 'Test@' at line 1
```

Comment: The table name `2017-08-11` is invalid, if you really have a table with the date as a name (if so I'm curious as to why) you need to wrap it in quotes

Comment: Thanks! It's just a simple booking system with a table per day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> INSERT INTO $date

It seems that there is a 2017-08-11 in $date var.

If you want to insert data into '2017-08-11' table, it should be escaped with ` symbol

```
try{
    $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `$date` (name, surname, email, phone, comment) VALUES (:name, :surname, :email, :phone, :comment)");
    $statement->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $statement->bindParam(':surname', $surname);
    $statement->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $statement->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
    $statement->bindParam(':comment', $comment);

    $statement->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    die("Connection to database failed: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: JimL did same to me in comments

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that 2017-08-11 is a table name, simply encase it in backticks.

```
    $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `$date` (name, surname, email, phone, comment) VALUES (:name, :surname, :email, :phone, :comment)");
```

Answer (score -1):

sorry but you can't use special character when using the prepare statement, so what MySQL is actually seeing is  `INSERT INTO $date (name, surname, email, phone, comment) VALUES (:name, :surname, :email, :phone, :comment)` which will trigger a syntax error.

here is a quick solution

```
 try{
$db->query("INSERT INTO $date (name, surname, email, phone, comment) VALUES ($name, $surname, $email, $phone, $comment)");

}
catch(PDOException $e){
    die("Connection to database failed: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Question is about prepared statements. Your solution implodes everything back to insecure query. Dig here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp